# Multi-tenant issue using django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We have an issue to make a multi-tenancy SaaS application using Django and django-rest-framework.

We would like to route to the correct database according to the url, and using django-rest-framework serializers.

But with django-rest-framework, we cannot specify the database we want to save to with serializers. We are able to request data by overriding the `get_queryset` method, and with the `using(<database>)` function.

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return SomeModel.objects.using(self.database)
```

If we want to save an instance to a custom database, we cannot use  `ModelSerializer`, we have to write each serializer using the `Serializer` class.
We can make a pull request to add the option to django-rest-framework [Multiple databases support #65 - django-rest-framework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/65)

Or, we can do something similar to this snippet : [Database Routing by URL](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2037/), it's quite old (2010) but still working. But we are not very comfortable with the idea of using the local thread to transfer variables.

How do we do this properly in 2017 ? Are there other options ?

Comment: I'm using django-multi-tenancy package in combination with the django-rest-framework. I'm not running into this issue (unless I'm not understanding the question). I have tenant A and tenant B. When logged in as a user in tenant A, at domain: `tenantA.mydomain.com` and point to the API endpoint `tenantA.mydomain.com/api/employees` (for example) the DRF will only show the `Employee` records for tenant A. Similarily with tenant B - I only see Employees for tenant B. I haven't done anything unique with the serializers -- just followed the DRF tutorial verbatim. How is this not working for you?

Comment: I meant to say I'm using the [django-tenant-schemas](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package -- not django-multi-tenancy